# Laravel 5 validation rules

Tags: laravel-5

previously I have used validation within a Request class e.g.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'userName' => 'required', 'min:3',
        'userEmail' => 'required|email',
        'departmentId' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

But I now have another form but I can't see any options within the documentation that might help me.

Basically, lets say I have a form with the same fields as the validation above.  The only time validation should fail is if **ALL** fields contain absolutely no data.  So if I put something like "hi" within the slug input and submit, it should pass the validation.

Would something like this be possible?

Thanks

Comment: firstly i would remove all 'required' rules, then add a hidden field in your form, and create a custom validator for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the `required_without_all` validation rule.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-without-all

> The field under validation must be present only when all of the other
>   specified fields are not present.

It would give you something like

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'userName' => 'required_without_all:userEmal,departmentId,slug','min:3',
        'userEmail' => 'required_without_all:userName,departmentId,slug|email'
         ...
    ];
}
```

But it's not very handy if you have a lot of fields.
If you have to deal with many fields, creating a custom validator might be a better solution.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules